# How to generate video preview thumbnails in Android

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails, preview

The scenario is when the user select a video from the gallery it will create a preview thumbnail of the selected video as a single image like [this](https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/thumbnails/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.jpg). Then both video and the preview thumbnails will be saved in a database. Is it possible to create a preview thumbnail in a single image?

Comment: I am planning to use this library https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar that is why I needed to create a preview thumbnail by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Glide**

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            mVidorExoPlayerView.setDefaultArtwork(resource);
// you can use "resource" as bitmap :)
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps You

Comment: It seems like you already have the thumbnail, what I need is to generate a preview thumbnail. Anyway thanks for your sample code it might help someone.

Comment: Did you try your **uri** instead of **url** in this code?

Comment: I am going to use the thumbnails as a preview while moving through seekbar like here https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar, not like a placeholder for playerview so it means that thumbnails is already created before streaming.

Comment: While the result should be like this https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/thumbnails/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.jpg

Comment: Glide does not support online video streaming so I cant use the url of the video

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an off the shelf library that would give you preview thumbnail containing several video frames at different times all stitched together.

But if I were to do this, I'd look for something that allows me to retrieve a video frame at a specified time. Then, given the video length, we could request frames at different time intervals and stitch them together to get one big preview thumbnail.

Android supports `[MediaMetadataRetriever][1]`, that allows extracting video frames (not sure if you've already tried this). AFAIK, it works well with `mp4` format.

Another option is to create the preview thumbnail on server side and use that (obviously has an overhead of downloading the thumbnail).

Comment: I am still searching for this, I will try extracting video frames using built in library provided by Android.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool named 'FFmpeg', it has a command to get the 1st image or even any images  at any time in it.

Comment: Is it a library?

Comment: Yes, I have used this library for more than half a year, so I can give this recommendation. The offical link is https://ffmpeg.org

Comment: How to implement this in android project, it says it support windows, iOS, and linux. Is this available for android?

Comment: Yes, the method which I use it: run the command at background as a process, after it finished, I will get the desired result from the path(folder)

Comment: could you give me a android sample project? I am not familiar with commands

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.webm -ss 00:00:07.000 -vframes 1 thumb.jpg.

This command can get only one picture on the time of 7th second, which the name of the video file is 'video.webm'.

Comment: How to run this command in run time of the app, for example when uploading the video and the thumbnails.

Comment: ffmpeg is an executable file, I guess your request is: run the command at the backstage to generate images before user open the folder with video files. then user upload files based on what images they have seen on user interface.

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg -i video.webm -ss 00:00:07.000 -vframes 1 thumb.jpg

This command can get only one picture on the time of 7th second, which the name of the video file is 'video.webm'.